# How to pass a specific value from Tuple into a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
variable1 = 1
variable2 = 2
a_tuple = (variable1, variable2)

def my_function(a):
    pass

my_function(a_tuple(variable1))
```

Is there a way I can pass a specific value from a tuple into a function? This is a terrible example, but all I need to know is if I can pass variable1 from the tuple into the function, I understand in this instance I could just pass in variable 1, but its for more complicated functions that will get its data from a tuple, and I don't like the look of that many variables, too messy.

```
variable1 = 1
variable2 = 2
a_tuple = (variable1, variable2)

def my_function(a):
    pass

my_function(*a_tuple)
```

This code would obviously provide an error as it unpacks the tuple and inserts 2 variables, to make this work in my program I would need a way to pass either variable1 or variable2 into the function. My question is can I define exactly which items from a tuple are passed into the function when calling the function? Latest version of Python if it matters.

P.S. I wrote print("hello world") for the first time 7 days ago, this is my first language and my first question I couldn't find an answer to. Go easy on me, and thank you for your time.

Comment: `my_function(a_tuple[0])` - or did I misunderstand your question? Also, your 'tuple' is actually a list.

Comment: Please strongly consider to do a [basic Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html). Indexing is a fundamental operation of the language.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that you've read some tutorial and/or this Python page in particular: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code you provided you don't have a tuple you have a list. But it is still pretty much the same.

In your example lets say that you wanted to pass the first variable you would do it like this:

```
my_function(a_tuple[0])
```

If you don't understand why there is a zero here and how does this work I highly suggest learning about lists before functions.

Comment: Thank you for your guiding answer. So to get ranges from multiple tuples into a function i have to do something like this, 'def my_function(a, b, c, d):' which requires 4 values, and 'my_function(*a_tuple[0:2],*b_tuple[0:2])' which i just tested and works, Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You just need to access individual elements of the tuple, using index notation:

my_function(a_tuple[0])

or

```
my_function(a_tuple[1])
```

You could, if you wanted, write a new function which takes a tuple and an index, and calls `my_function` with the appropriate element:

```
def my_other_function(tuple, index):
    return my_function(tuple[index])
```

But I don't see how there would be much gain in doing that.

Answer (score -1):

you can index a tuple or use the index method.

```
    def my_function(a):
        pass

    my_function(a_tuple[0])
```

if you want to get the index of a value use the index() method

```
    a_tuple.index(variable1) #this will return 0
```

Comment: What's the point of suggesting ``tup[tup.index(val)]``? Why not just use the value directly?

Comment: ofc he can use the index directly or pass the value directly. I wanted to make another solution to show him how to get an index or value by the value itself. I know it would be much easier to just pass the index or the value, but I don't know what he is going to do with the Code.

You are right that a index or value is much more neater

Comment: The point is that this answers suggests to compute the value *from the value*. There is absolutely no information gained from doing this. ``tup[tup.index(val)]`` is *guaranteed* to be equal to just ``val``.

Comment: MisterMiyagi would answer better if he read the question. I stated I knew I could just pass in the values, but I wanted to grab specifics from a tuple, multiple tuples actually I just simplified the question before asking. Maybe too much.

Comment: So MisterMiyagi is right if he says it has no additional information, but I wanted to give Grave an overview of possible features with tuples. I edited my answer for further visitors. Still with the information of the index-method.

Comment: @Grave The point is that using ``tup.index`` *also* requires being able to pass in the values, namely to ``tup.index``.

Comment: Question answered a while ago, index, thanks guys.